# How can I consume a navision web service from a Sharepoint Designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, web-services

I'm trying to call a navision web service (oData) from a sharepoint designer workflow, but I have problems. The problem comes from the type of authentication, they use NTLM, and I do not know how to pass this on the call to the service. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the calling web service action of SharePoint workflow, this is not available to pass Windows credential to the web service, please check this similiar thread:

[SharePoint Designer Wokflow, Http web service action, pass windows credentials](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed7131d3-cb15-4a94-9a73-fbca635ead2b/sharepoint-designer-wokflow-http-web-service-action-pass-windows-credentials?forum=sharepointcustomization)

This needs to do with C# code, set the web service credential like this:

```
pService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password","domain");
```

[Invoke a WebService that needs Windows Authentication](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2006/12/01/Invoke-a-WebService-that-needs-Windows-Authentication.aspx)